# why browsersync reload multiple times whe a file is changed?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, browser-sync

I have a project with `angularjs`. All the environment is set under `nodejs` with `gulp` and `bower` dependencies.

I have a problem: every time a file is changed, the browser reloads multiple times.

So, I think is problem is related to the `browsersync` configuration, how I can fix it?

[image: the image show that the process reload multiple times every time a file is changed]

```js
// ////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// EDIT CONFIG OBJECT BELOW !!!
// 
// jsConcatFiles => list of javascript files (in order) to concatenate
// buildFilesFoldersRemove => list of files to remove when running final build
// // //////////////////////////////////////////////

var config = {
 jsConcatFilesApi: [
  './js/initapp/*.js',
  './js/services/*.js',
  './js/charts/*.js',

 ],
 jsConcatFilesNavigation: [
  './js/navigation/**/*.js',

 ], 
 buildFilesFoldersRemove:[
  './build/scss/', 
  './build/js/!(*.min.js)',
  './build/bower.json',
  './build/node_modules/',
  './build/gulpfile.js',
  './build/package.json',
  './build/maps/',
  './build/readme.md'
 ]
};


// ////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Required taskes
// gulp build
// bulp build:serve
// // /////////////////////////////////////////////

var gulp = require('gulp'),
 sass = require('gulp-sass'),
 sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
 autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
 browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
 reload = browserSync.reload,
 concat = require('gulp-concat'),
 uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
 rename = require('gulp-rename'),
 del = require('del');


// ////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Log Errors
// // /////////////////////////////////////////////

function errorlog(err){
 console.error(err.message);
 this.emit('end');
}


// ////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Scripts Tasks
// ///////////////////////////////////////////////

gulp.task('scriptsApi', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.jsConcatFilesApi)
 .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(concat('temp.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .on('error', errorlog)
  .pipe(rename('d3AcnaDane.min.js'))  
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/min/'))

    .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});

gulp.task('scriptsNavigation', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.jsConcatFilesNavigation)
 .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(concat('temp.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .on('error', errorlog)
  .pipe(rename('navigationAcnaDane.min.js'))  
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/min/'))

    .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});


// ////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Styles Tasks
// ///////////////////////////////////////////////

gulp.task('styles', function() {
 gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
   .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
   .on('error', errorlog)
   .pipe(autoprefixer({
             browsers: ['last 3 versions'],
             cascade: false
         })) 
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
  .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});


// ////////////////////////////////////////////////
// HTML Tasks
// // /////////////////////////////////////////////

gulp.task('html', function(){
    gulp.src('**/*.html')
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});


// ////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Browser-Sync Tasks
// // /////////////////////////////////////////////

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});

// task to run build server for testing final app
gulp.task('build:serve', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});


// ////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Build Tasks
// // /////////////////////////////////////////////

// clean out all files and folders from build folder
gulp.task('build:cleanfolder', function (cb) {
 del([
  './build/**'
 ], cb);
});

// task to create build directory of all files
gulp.task('build:copy',function(){
    return gulp.src('./**/*/')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

// task to removed unwanted build files
// list all files and directories here that you don't want included
gulp.task('build:remove', function (cb) {
 del(config.buildFilesFoldersRemove, cb);
});

gulp.task('build', ['build:copy', 'build:remove']);


// ////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Watch Tasks
// // /////////////////////////////////////////////

gulp.task ('watch', function(){
 gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
 gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', ['scriptsApi']);
 gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', ['scriptsNavigation']);
   gulp.watch('**/*.html', ['html']);
});


gulp.task('default', ['scriptsApi','scriptsNavigation', 'styles', 'html', 'browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Can you share your gulp file?

Comment: done, i have share an snipet in the question. thank you very much.

Comment: well i have commented  gulp.task('build:serve', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});  so the error persist, and it reloaded more than 5 times.